# Generic type inference doesnt take polymorphism into account

Tags: c#, generics

Hi here is my example let's say

```
class A { }
class B : A { }
```

```
void test<T>(T clazz)
{
     Console.WriteLine("clazz type = {0} T type = {1}",
                 clazz.GetType().Name,
                 typeof(T).Name);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{         
    A b = new B(); 
    test(b);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The result is clazz= B T= A ????? why inference generic type doesn't take into account polymorphism ?

Comment: Why is this down voted? It's a good question, the title is misleading, that's just because the OP misdiagnosed the source of the problem. Really it should be "what's the difference between typeof and GetType()?".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The result is clazz= B T= A ????? why inference generic type doesn't take into account polymorphism ?

Type inference is performed at *compile* time. The *compile* time type of the variable `b` is `A`, so the compiler infers that you meant:

```
test<A>(b);
```

The fact that the value of `b` at execution time is `B` is irrelevant, because that's too late for type inference.

As of C# 4 you can defer the type inference until execution time using `dynamic` though:

```
dynamic b = new B();
test(b);
```

Comment: Yes this is what i noticed !! :( it is sad, any reason for that, any way to make it work ?

Comment: @Ahmed: Well it's working as the language is designed to work already. The reason is described in my answer - you shouldn't expect the compiler to make a compile-time decision based on an execution-time value. But see my edit for an approach using dynamic typing.

Comment: Thank you very much in fact, this is what i ended up doing in my real case i will put this question as answered when SO will allow me to :) thank you again

Answer (score 3):

`typeof` works at compile time, that is, it can't know about the polymorphism, because at that time it's not yet decided what type the actual object stored in the variable is. `GetType()`, however, works at runtime and can know the actual type.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think generics is the issue. It has to do with the the differences between `typeof` and `GetType`. `GetType` determines the type at run time, `typeof` determines the type of that instance at compile time. You declared the variable as type A, therefor that is the compile time type. Whether or not you assign an instance of an inherited class to that reference doesn't matter, you declared it as type A, that's what `typeof` returns. `GetType` is returning the type of the instance that reference currently points to, it doesn't care what you declared the variable as, but what the instance actually is.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an expression of type `A` to a parameter that determines a generic `T`, `T` is going to be `A`. The *value* of the object doesn’t come into play; it could be `null` and everything would still work.

(You can think of it as the type being determined at compile-time, but that’s not necessarily true, just necessarily possible.)